Car AC gas leak - am I being misled?
for the past 4 years I was required to fill in new gas into my car AC system due to a leak on a yearly basis, my mechanic could not locate the source of the leak (using the standard detection procedure which involves vacuum and the insertion of a phosphorus material which can be visually seen in the naked eye).
Recently a class action has been ruled against the local importer - regarding a factory malfunction in the assembly of the internal AC condenser, which led this part to malfunction and leak gas. the importer is now required to replace this part free of charge for a set of car manufacturers.
I went to the official garage, and they diagnosed the issue.
after a day they came up with the conclusion:
there is an oil leak in the shaft of the compressor.
now two questions :

an oil leak usually means poor performance compression wise - but once I fill up gas in the AC it works perfectly.
does an oil leak necessarily mean gas leak? we are talking about two different "areas" of the compressor. the pistons oil is not mixed with the refrigerant gas.

am I being miseld with a false diagnostic?

1)Your 'mechanic' clearly does not know how to diagnose, troubleshoot and repair vehicle ac systems. Trained correctly, anyone can find a leak. You're being misled into believing a refill every year is needed when it's leaking from damage. Every vehicle comes from the factory as a sealed ac system,  until something occurs when pressurized systems leak. New vehicle warranty covers factory faults. Wear and tear occurs when a leak disrupts ac operation whether under warranty or not.
2)Trained people can use electronic leak detectors, sniffers, or dye injected at factory assembly or added with refrigerant for troubleshooting. Dye, refrigerant and oil mix and circulate throughout a system. A leak will release all three with oil and dye marking the leak site. An inexpensive UV blacklight will make dye glow greenish yellow.
3)Unscrupulous repair shops are everywhere, taking advantage of vehicle owners unfamiliar with ac repairs with many strongly suggesting compressor failure. Oil leaking from a compressor can be seen, sometimes hidden from view as the compressor clutch assembly hides oil and dye unless trained eyes look for it .
4)If the 'official' repair shop determines compressor damage from a seal, refrigerant, oil and dye will leak out and mark the area.
